# Table name turned to uppercase

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate5.

My application.propperties have:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

And my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document", schema = "test")
```

When I execute findAll, the following error is returned:

> Table "DOCUMENT" not found; SQL statement: SELECT * FROM document

I'm unable to get entity names as described in name attribute. Always applies an 'uppercase'

**EDIT:**
The error has appeared when I'm trying to exclude HikariCP dependency. If I don't disable the dependency, properties works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Define table name with `backticks`  like shown below:

```
 @Table(name="`document`")?
```

This should work in `hibernate`

Comment: Not tested but I suppose that if your suggestion works for tablename I will have the same problem for fields names and I think that have no sense to edit all my entities to put `` so by the moment, I'm going to maintain hikariCP dependency

Comment: @canillas Then make your database case insensitive

Comment: Unfortunately we can't change database configuration but thanks for the suggestion.